# Match text from one column with another column (vlookup + like)

Tags: r, stringr

I'm trying to perform a match of 2 columns but without success. I have one `DF1` with 2 columns, `Id` and `JSON`. In the second `DF2`, I have one column with a pattern to be matched in each row for `DF1$json` (something like vlookup + like function).

As an output, I'd like to get `DF1$Id` but only where any of `DF2` is matched with `DF1$json`.

[image]

I've tried some combinations with `str_detect` but it doesn't work on non-vector values. Maybe some tricks with `grep` or `stringr` functions?

For example:

```
str_detect(DF1$json, fixed(DF2[1,1], ignore_case = TRUE))
```

Comment: Please share a [reproductible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using `dput(DF1)` and `dput(DF2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Id = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"),
  json = c("{xxx:yyy:zzz};{mmm:zzz:vvv}", "{ccc:yyy:zzz};{ddd:zzz:vvv}", "{ttt:yyy:zzz};{mmm:zzz:vvv}", "{uuu:yyy:zzz};{mmm:zzz:vvv}")
)
matches <- c("mmm:zzz:vvv", "mmm:yyy:zzz")

library(stringr) # needed for str_extract_all()
```

**Solution using data.table**

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)

df1[, match := any(str_extract_all(json, "(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})")[[1]] %in% matches), by = Id]
df1[match == T, .(Id)]
```

**Solution using dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  mutate(match = any(str_extract_all(json, "(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})")[[1]] %in% matches)) %>%
  filter(match == T) %>%
  select(Id)
```

Or just directly filter()

```
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Id) %>% 
  filter(any(str_extract_all(json, "(?<=\\{).+?(?=\\})")[[1]] %in% matches)) %>%
  select(Id)
```

**Output on both methods**

```
   Id
1: AA
2: CC
3: DD
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this give you the expected result :

```
my_df <- data.frame("id" = c("AA", "BB", "CC", "DD"),
                "json" = c("{x:y:z};{m:z:v}", "{c:y:z};{d:z:v}", "{t:y:z};{m:z:v}", "{u:y:z};{m:z:v}"),
                "pattern" = c("m:z:v", "t:y:z", "m:z:v", "t"),
                stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


my_f <- function(x) {
  my_var <- paste(grep(pattern = my_df[x, "pattern"], x = my_df$json), collapse = " ")
  return (my_var)
}
my_df$Value <- lapply(1:nrow(my_df), my_f)
```

Comment: Hey, DF2 (or 'pattern' in your example) is a separate one column DF with different number of rows than DF1. Looking at your function I think you are close to expected output. I'll try to adjust your function if I manage